# css files delay before updating

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, reload

I'm using Dreamweaver to update a website. When I upload the style.css file, Safari and Chrome don't recognize the changes for a while. Here's what I'm doing.

- Edit in Dreamweaver
- Upload either with Dreamweaver or Fetch
- If I use Fetch to view style.css as a text file on the server, I see
  my changes, so it's getting uploaded.
- I'm using Safari and Chrome in Incognito mode, which I understand means that it
  won't cache anything, and in theory, every refresh should reload all
  the files. However, when I look at style.css using the web inspector,
  I see the old file.
- In Web Inspector, while I'm looking at style.css, I refresh it and
  nothing changes.
- I've emptied the cache and refreshed. Nothing changes.
- If I File>Open the index.html page from my hard drive (which calls
  style.css), the browsers show the changes.

The problem is that Safari and Chrome aren't recognizing the changes on the server. I saw a suggestion to call the stylesheet with href="css/style.css?v={random number/string}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css", but that didn't seem to help.

If I wait long enough (5-10 minutes), eventually things get updated. Is there a way to get instantaneous css updates to the browsers?

Comment: You can just use `CTRL + F5` to flush cache and refresh page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so I'm using Option-Command-R in Safari and Shift-Command-R in Chrome with no success.

Comment: Thanks - I think the issue is the same as the question you referenced, but I'm not sure I have the chops to implement it, since I don't know php. I'll experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browsers are caching the CSS file to be more efficient and have no idea that changes have been made.

The versioning you mentioned in the original question should do the trick. Keep in mind it needs to be changed (to whatever you want) every time you want the browser to re-fetch it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css?ver=2.0">
```

Comment: Thank you - do I need to change something in the css file itself to match what comes after the question mark (e.g., ver=2.0 or whatever)?

Comment: Nope, only here :)

Comment: It's working. I'm working my way from ?v1a to v1b, etc., to currently v1i. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this post.
The solution worked for me.

This oen:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css?ver=2.0">
```